# Jena; java heap space error when iterating superclasses

Tags: java, jena, owl

Using Jena in Eclipse platform, I'm writing a piece of code that for a given class, gets all its super classes. I know common Java heap space problems and I've allocated 1 G.B of memory for accomplishing the task, though it triggers: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)exception.`

[Here](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~%20oromero/EUCarRental.owl) is the ontology I'm using.

my code usually fails after 8th iteration or less more on  if. Can anyone tell me the reason for that or what to do? I know this ontology is a bit large but is what happening logical? (When I use `OntModelSpec` without a reasoner 'e.g. `OWL_DL_MEM` ', everything is OK).

```
ModelFactory model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
    this.model.read(convertPathToURI("some-path", "eu-car-rental.rdf"), "RDF/XML");     

    ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = getClassByURI("RentalAgreement").listSuperClasses();
    while (classes.hasNext()){
        OntClass oc = classes.next();
        System.out.println("something");
    }
    System.out.println("----finished----");
```

Here is function getClassByURI

```
public OntClass getClassByURI (String classURI)
{
    String myNS = model.getNsPrefixURI("");
    Resource r = model.getResource(myNS + classURI );       
    OntClass cls = (OntClass) r.as( OntClass.class );
    //System.out.println("++++++++++++  " + cls.getURI());
    //List<OntProperty> exItr = getClassProperties(cls,2, true);            
    return cls;
}
```

Comment: 1GB is A LOT of memory. It is almost impossible to tell you what is wrong without having access to the entire code. But, there is something you can do: launch your application using a profiler.  Java comes in with a profiler (I believe since Java 6). There are tutorials on how to do this.  The profiler will help you find what is taking so much memory. Most likely, this is caused by poor design, but it could also be caused by trying to load HUGE amounts of data into memory. For the looks of it, it doesn't seem to be related to `PropertyCardinality`.

Comment: Actually, this almost the whole code.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious that would create a lot of objects in your code. However, I cannot see anything that would benefit from reasoning as well - if you use a smaller ontology, do you see differences between the output with reasoning and the output without?

Comment: the profiler mentioned by hfontanez is jvisualvm

Comment: I edited the question, more minimal code is causing the exception.

Comment: @Ignazio I need the reasoner in other tasks, that was only a part.

Comment: May the problem be with the ontology? Using Protege 5 it's classified without problems.

Comment: Can You tell us what is the object "bh" and how do You create it?

Comment: @maslan please leave it out. I deleted it. bh was originally an instance of a class called OWL handler but I copied its constructor code and put it at the beginning.

Comment: Ok, so I also do not see anything really suspicious. If You never tried profiling it's time to learn something new I guess ;) You should try to look into Your heap dump and simply analyze, what excess objects are polluting Your memory. The example tool ( I like it) is MAT: https://eclipse.org/mat/
You can find how to get a heap dump in Getting Started section I guess :)

Comment: @MedianHilal The code in the question is not really a complete minimal example.  See my answer (where I can reproduce your problem) for an example of a complete minimal example.  It's code that anyone can download and run that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @maslan This does appear to be some sort of bug in Jena or in the ontology, rather than anything in MedianHilal's question.  I was able to pretty quickly reproduce it.  Profiling may help, but it probably won't point to something that would be easy for anyone but a Jena dev to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem. In the future, please provide *complete, minimal, working examples*.  The code that follows is good example;  anyone can copy it and run it.  The code:

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class OWLSuperclassExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
        model.read("http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~%20oromero/EUCarRental.owl");
        OntClass rentalAgreement = 
            model.getOntClass("http://www.owl-ontologies.com/unnamed.owl#RentalAgreement");
        ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = rentalAgreement.listSuperClasses();
        while ( classes.hasNext() ) {
            System.out.println( "Superclass: " + classes.next() );
        }
        System.out.println("Completed.");
    }
}
```

```
Superclass: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f4c
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f4b
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f46
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f4a
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f4f
Superclass: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f4d
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f47
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f48
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f50
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f4e
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f51
Superclass: 75bdf39:14b07a39a79:-7f49
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 92463104 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/taylorj/tmp/workspace/taylorj-jena-examples/hs_err_pid21802.log
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000deee4000, 92463104, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

It looks like it's some kind of a bug, or at the least, unexpected behavior, in the Jena rule reasoner.  There are a few things that could be the culprit:

1. Jena's OWL reasoners are *logically incomplete* by design.  That means that there are legal OWL conclusions that they won't produce.  That's by design, because the OWL semantics can't be completely realized using rule-based reasoning.
2. Jena's OWL reasoners are for *OWL1*.  If this ontology has parts of OWL2, that could interfere.
3. Jena's OWL reasoners are for a sort of OWL Full, which has fewer restrictions on what triples can appear than OWL DL.  It might be the case that rules are being applied where you wouldn't expect them to be, and that could interfere.

Comment: This is an interesting one, not a simple out of memory but a VM crash. I've only seen these occasionally, and they were not easy to replicate. This might be good stuff to investigate.

Comment: @Ignazio Definitely.  I was actually expecting to be able to run things without a problem (to highlight that problem was elsewhere in OP's code; the way things like this usually turn out), but sure enough, there's something happening here.

Comment: That was right, the problem is with Jena built in reasoner, using Pellet has solved the problem.